# Node Orm2 ExtendsTo NO_SUCH_TABLE

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-orm2

I am trying to get the NODE-ORM2 extends to work. I am unable to find an all inclusive example to follow, only some partial that start at the model definition level (without reference to the DB).

Essentially I have two models A and B where there is a *one to one* relationship between them where B.AId is the foreign key to A.id (i probably should have established that in the db statements for simplicity, but orm2 doesn't read these relationships.

I don't understand why it is looking for an a_b relationship table.  Nor do I understand how to form the relationship between the two Models.

Can anybody help?  in the hasOne relationship we get to specify the fields - that seems to be missing here.

**DB:**

```
create table A
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT key,
  `addedOn` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1718087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

create table B
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT KEY,
  AId int(11),
  `addedOn` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1718087 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into A (addedOn)values('2012-02-02')
insert into B (AId, addedOn)values((select id from A), '2012-02-04')
```

**Models:**

```
// User Model
module.exports = function (db, cb) {
    console.log('ORM loading \'A\' model')

    var A = db.define('A', {
        id              : Number,
        addedOn         : Date
    }) ;

    var B = A.extendsTo('B', {
        id              : Number,
        AId             : Number,
        addedOn         : Date
    })
    return cb()
}
```

**Retrieval:**

```
    var A = req.db.models.A
    A.get(1718087, {autoFetch: true}, function(err, a){
        a.getB(function(err,  b){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(b, null, 4))
        })

        console.log(JSON.stringify(a, null, 4))
    })
```

**Exception:**

```
ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE: Table 'mydb.a_b' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the problem by specifying the table name and the foreign key inside of the Model definition:

```
var A = db.define('A', {
    id              : Number,
    addedOn         : Date
}) ;

var B = A.extendsTo('B', {
    id              : Number,
    AId             : Number,
    addedOn         : Date
}, {field: 'AId', table: 'B'})
```

Let's look inside of Extend.js for some of the reasoning:

```
 exports.prepare = function (db, Model, associations, association_properties, model_fields) {
Model.extendsTo = function (name, properties, opts) {
    opts = opts || {};

    var assocName = opts.name || ucfirst(name);
    var association = {
        name           : name,
        table          : opts.table || (Model.table + '_' + name),

        field          : util.wrapFieldObject(opts.field, Model, Model.table, Model.properties) || util.formatField(Model, Model.table, false, false),
        getAccessor    : opts.getAccessor || ("get" + assocName),
        setAccessor    : opts.setAccessor || ("set" + assocName),
        hasAccessor    : opts.hasAccessor || ("has" + assocName),
        delAccessor    : opts.delAccessor || ("remove" + assocName)
    };
```

And then util.formatField:

```
        association_key : "{name}_{field}",
```

So unless specified it assumes the table is the primary table concatenated to the model name. And the foreign key is primary_table concatenated with the field parameter.

In my case, without specifying the table and field, the node-orm code was looking fora table A_B with a foreign key A_id.